# ignore missing channels when creating conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, persistence, virtualenv, conda

I am creating a conda environment:

```
conda env export --name root > myEnv.yml
```

I manually replace 'root' with 'myEnv' within a file.
This is done on a shared machine.
Then I move to another system and I do:

```
conda env create -f myEnv.yml

name: my_env
channels:
file://somewhere//
otherpublicrepos
```

Unfortunately, in the file there was one private channel, which I had to remove

Now I get (one by one) plently of missing package errors from those that were in file:// and I have to remove them from the file manually.

How to install only what is available  in public repos but finally create an environment?

---

the -q option did not help, `conda create` outputs

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:   - ALIB 3.2.1 1
```

and returns silently without creating an environment

Comment: What happens if you use the -q option to suppress errors?

Comment: it runs. it only says ResolvePackageNotFound:   - ALIB 3.2.1 1

Comment: if I relist the environments afterwards, it is not there

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way to do this. I think you'll have to manually remove the unavailable packages from the YAML file.

Comment: I have 380+ libraries :(

Comment: don't you think there should be?

Comment: Possibly... conda is open source, feel free to add a new option! (I am not affiliated with Continuum nor a developer of conda, so my statement does not indicate that the conda developers would find such a feature useful) :-)